# BootStrap 4 does not set the Active Page on the Navbar

Tags: php, jquery, nav

after searching through the question and replies I still cannot get the NAVBAR to add class "active" on the current page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-link").on("click", function(){
        $(".nav-link").find(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

I do see the **class added** and when the new page load the class is gone..?? i cannot understand this jquery.

the work around that I have found is to provide variable

`<?php pageID = "index"; ?>` on each page and in the respective 'nav-link' a class

`<?php echo(pageID=="index") ? "active" : "" ?>`

btw the navbar code is in the header.php which is loaded on each page `include('header.php');`

looking for guidance on how to use the jquery instead of work around

Comment: Show corresponding html code

Comment: Why would the class persist when you reload the page? You need to use php or JS to set the active class when the page loads (currently you only do it on click)

Comment: you beter add your html navbar code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workaround is, in fact, the typical way to achieve this. Javascript will not persist the changes it did through your navigation. To achieve want you want to do in JS, you probably want to use `localStorage`

```
/* Sample code */
localStorage.setItem('activeMenu', 'blog');
$(function(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('activeMenu') === 'blog') {
    $('#blogNavLink').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

If you want to do it in PHP, you could probably use a PHP variable or a hidden input that would contain the selector and use it in JS.

```
$activeMenu = 'blog';
<input type="hidden" id="menuItem" value="<?= $activeMenu ?>">
$(function(){
  if ($('#menuItem').val() === 'blog') {
    $('#blogNavLink').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

Comment: The `localStorage` option won't work the first time a user visits the site (nothing will be active because nothing will be in localStorage)